# Rest API get Content-Length of Body

Tags: php, api, rest

I got a Problem. Im working on a Datatransfer to a Restful API at the Moment. All the arrays and everything and json objects should be fine, but i just do not understand how to determine the Content-Length of my Body?

```
$http = new Client([
        'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token["access_token"], 'Transfer-Encoding' => 'chunked', 'Content-Encoding' => 'chunked']
    ]);
```

This is my code at the moment. But the Answer thats coming back is always

```
HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.
```

Can you help me to determine the right Content-Length?

Cheers!

Comment: To you array add: `'Content-Length' => strlen($content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to do it.

If you have content in variable then add to your headers array `'Content-Length' => strlen($var)`

You can also use output buffering and get length with function `ob_get_length()`

`'Content-Length' => ob_get_length()`

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php) you will find example